# How can I compile a Titanium project using an old SDK (< 6.0.0.GA)?

Tags: android, android-studio, titanium, appcelerator

I currently have 2 Titanium projects. One uses the latest SDK (6.0.4.GA), the other uses an old one (5.2.2.GA). When I build the first one, everything works fine. I can generate the APK, install it on Genymotion, distribute it, etc. The problem is: when I try to build the second one (the one that uses SDK 5.2.2.GA), the CLI doesn't recognize the installed SDKs. Both projects are targeting Android SDK API 23. Any ideas how to compile the old one? As SDK version 6 removes Ti.include(), upgrading the SDK version is not an option.

I'm running the following command

```
appc ti build -p android -b
```

Here is the output

```
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 6.2.0
Copyright (c) 2014-2017, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2017-05-08 15:08:14

Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.12.4
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 8589934592

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 4.6.0
  npm Version                 = 2.15.9

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.12

Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 5.2.2.GA
  SDK Path                    = /Users/inovacao/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.2.GA
  Target Platform             = android

Command
  /usr/local/bin/node /Users/inovacao/.appcelerator/install/6.2.0/package/node_modules/titanium/lib/titanium.js build -p android -b --config-file /var/folders/63/7nt43kd11p3f3dg463vfd3rrrcyq8h/T/build-1494266892279.json --log-level info --no-banner --project-dir /Users/inovacao/Documents/eMob/emob-transformation

[ERROR] Target Android SDK API 23 is not installed
```

If I run `appc ti sdk select 6.0.4.GA` and then `appc ti info`, I get the following about Android:

```
Android SDK
  Android Executable          = not found
  ADB Executable              = /Users/inovacao/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
  SDK Path                    = /Users/inovacao/Library/Android/sdk

Android NDK
  NDK Path                    = /Users/inovacao/Library/Android/android-ndk-r9d
  NDK Version                 = r9d (64-bit)

Android Platforms
  1) android-23
    Name                      = Android 6.0
    API Level                 = 23
    Revision                  = 3
    Skins                     = HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800, WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
    ABIs                      = 
    Path                      = /Users/inovacao/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23
  2) android-25
    Name                      = Android 7.1.1
    API Level                 = 25
    Revision                  = 2
    Skins                     = HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800, WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
    ABIs                      = 
    Path                      = /Users/inovacao/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-25

Android Add-Ons
  None

Android Emulators
  None
```

But, when I run `appc ti sdk select 5.2.2.GA` and then `appc ti info`, I get this result:

```
Android SDK
  Android Executable          = /Users/inovacao/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android
  ADB Executable              = /Users/inovacao/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
  SDK Path                    = /Users/inovacao/Library/Android/sdk

Android NDK
  NDK Path                    = /Users/inovacao/Library/Android/android-ndk-r9d
  NDK Version                 = r9d (64-bit)

Android Platforms
  None

Android Add-Ons
  None

Android Emulators
  None
```

[EDIT 1] I tried using the following:

appc cli            : `appc use latest`, `appc use 5.2.2`
node                : `n 4.6.0`, `n 4.4.4`, `n 4.2.0`, `n 4.0.0`
Android NKD         : r14b, r10e, r9d
Android build-tools : 25.0.3, 23.0.1

Still, no luck

Comment: did you try just compiling the app without running the `sdk select` part? I you just set the proper SDK inside the tiapp.xml it will use it to compile it.

Comment: Yes, I did. Still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a full day of hassling I finally figured it out. It was the Android SDK tools version that was not compatible with Titanium SDK 5.2.2.GA. I downloaded Android SDK V23.0.2 from [this site](https://android-sdk.en.uptodown.com/mac/old), got the tools folder and replaced the existing one in my Android SDK home `~/Library/Android/sdk` folder.

Now, the site does not give you the platform-tools folder, so the result is kind of a Frankenstein, with the tools from one version, the platform-tools from another and the build-tools from a third one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must install an appc local environment for your 5.2.2.GA project and use the global installation of appc to 6.0.4.GA project to avoid conflicts.